# How to Reuse Google Analytics For Firebase Event Parameters

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

#### Issue

In Firestore Analytics I am unable to re-use custom unique *text* event parameters created.

#### Attempted Solution

Per the [Firebase guidelines](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) *10 textual custom event parameters* may be used. In the Firebase console it specifies these parameters can be unique: *You can have up to 10 **unique** text parameters..*

[image]

For my event named *Archived* I have defined 7 custom text parameters as seen below: *content_type*, *creator*, *feed_type*, *item_id*, *item_name*, *quality_score*, and *timestamp*.

[image]

I am unable to re-use the same 7 custom text parameters in the event named *SAVED*. These event parameters should not be counted as unique since they are exactly as defined in the first event *ARCHIVED*.
[image]

Comment: As far as I can see in your question you're only asking about Google Analytics for Firebase (formerly known as Firebase Analytics). Why did you tag with Firestore and Realtime Database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My initial thought was because Firestore and Realtime Database are related features of Firebase. Thank you for updating the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does not imply that you should be able to re-use them. If you could, then you could simply make 10 generic parameters and use them for every event. I do agree that it's very limiting, but they are trying to push users to connect their Firebase instance with BigQuery.

I suggest that you do just this and analyse your custom parameters from there as I am unaware of any way to bypass the 10 parameter limit. For us there has been no downside to connecting with BigQuery, even with millions of users it has cost us nothing/close to nothing.

Comment: Great to know! I just finished setting up saving of all of my major user action events into Firestore. The next step is setting up a Cloud Function to send every event to BigQuery when the action is received in Firestore. I'm currently an indy developer, so glad to know the cost won't be a factor.

Comment: It is worth noting that the costs may increase eventually :)